# WINFORM or WPF: How to trigger custom event inside the constructor of the class that emits it

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a userControl11 (either in winform or wpf) which has a ValueChanged custom event. If I put it in client form and in form_load set its value to 100, it will trigger the ValueChanged event. But if I set this value inside the constructor of UserControl1 the custom event won't trigger. How can I force it to do so ?

whatever the technical reason, functionally it does make sense. If the object is initializing its value from some sources unknown to the client form and the client form has a textbox bound to this usercontrol value, it is sure convenient that it could refresh its textbox at any time including when the form loads just using one single event handler. Without this the client form has to create another initializer for this bound textbox at form load.

Below the source code of my trials in winform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void userControl11_ValueChanged()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(userControl11.Value.ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // This will trigger ValueChanged Event
            userControl11.Value = 100;
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace customevent
{
    [DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private int m_value;

        public delegate void ValueChangedHandler();
        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Value changed.")]
        public event ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged;

        public int Value
        {
            get { return m_value; }
            set { 
                m_value = value;
                if (ValueChanged != null)
                {
                    ValueChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // this won't trigger ValueChanged Event
            this.Value = 100;
        }
        public UserControl1(int iValue)
        {
            this.Value = iValue;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within the class you can use the On Events.

On events are protected, so you can't trigger them from the hosting form, but from within the class you can call them. (if you want to trigger them manually from outside the calss, you'll need to expose them with a custom method.)

```
public UserControl1(IEnumerable<Action> subscribers)   {

   this.OnValueChanged(new EventArgs());
   this.Value = 100;
}
```

Read about the specific event you are calling, and send the proper EventArgs to the event.
The On events are the methods that call the events.
The On events are protected, you can overload them, just remember to use the base function at the end.

**Edit:**

According to the [Event Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011%28VS.80%29.aspx) in MSDN, each event has a matching method called OnEvent (the same name with the On prefix).
These methods are used to raise the base events.

The EventArgs that are passed are the same as the event of the same name, so if you want to see the passing arguments, then read the MSDN description of the actual event.

I would suggest to just subscribe to the event, and use breakpoints to see what the EventArgs look like.

Comment: Could you point me to some doc about OnValueChanged I'm confused about the one I can find on Google ?

Comment: You're right, there's nothing useful in MSDN or google. I'll add some more information to the post.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that within the constructor no subscribers have the opportunity to attach to the event. The `Form_Load` only gets called when the control is displayed so there is a chance to subscribe to it between construction and display.

With your first example the control is attempting to raise the event but as there are no subscribers so it doesn't get called.

The only way to raise the event is to pass in the subscribers into the constructor...

```
  public UserControl1(IEnumerable<Action> subscribers)
  {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ValueChanged += () => 
           {
               foreach(var subcriber in subscribers)
                    subscriber();
           } 

        this.Value = 100;
  }
```

Comment: So how can I have it called somehow or is it impossible ?

Comment: The only way to add subscribers in the constructor is if you pass in them as part of the constructor arguments. However if you use the designer to build your UI then this is rather difficult. I will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is a fairly natural consequence of setting the value in the *constructor*.  By design, the constructor of a class initializes the object's initial state.  Nothing has changed just yet when you assign the property, there is no Changed event that should be raised.  As written, the event does actually get raised, there's just no opportunity for anybody to subscribe to the event yet.  This works by accident, what you really should do is assign the m_value member.

So if the form is curious about the *default* value of the property then it should just read it back.  You could also call the userControl11_ValueChanged() method directly for example to take advantage of its side-effects.

If you do want to always generate the event with good odds that a subscriber sees it then assign the property in the UserControl's OnLoad method override (or Load event).

Answer (score 0):

Raising events in the constructor doesn't really make sense (unless it's a static event): since the object isn't fully initialized yet, no other object had a chance to subscribe the event yet...

Comment: Functionally it does make sense. If the object is initializing its value from some sources and the client form has a textbox bound to this value, it is sure convenient that he could refresh its textbox at any time including when the form loads.